# Laravel 8 Notifications - toSlack or toNexmo functions not firing

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-notification

I am having an issue with Slack and Nexmo.

Both are specified in the via function, but it seems that upon trigger, Laravel isn't hitting the `toSlack` or `toNexmo` functions, or the `routeNotificationForSlack` function. I have tried to exit or print something to prove it has gotten to this point but neither work.

I have also tried clearing cache (using DDEV as a local environment).

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage;


class PaymentReceived extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['nexmo' , 'mail' , 'database' , 'slack'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the Slack representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return SlackMessage
     */
    public function toSlack($notifiable)
    {
        exit;
        return (new SlackMessage)
            ->from('Ghost', ':ghost:')
            ->content('That was some good food.');
    }

    /**
     * Route notifications for the Slack channel.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForSlack($notification)
    {

        return 'MY_HOOK_HERE';
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @patricus below I needed to add this on my User Model instead. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: In your `toSlack` method, there is an `exit;` call, right before the return statement. That might be why.

Answer (score 0):

The `routeNotificationForSlack()` method belongs on the notifiable object, not the notification.

If the notifiable object does not have this method defined, the slack notification channel will never actually call the `toSlack()` method.

Move your `routeNotificationForSlack()` method to the notifiable object and you should see your `toSlack()` method start to get called.